# VS2017 throws Unknow Error after Live Unit Test set to start on a solution

Tags: visual-studio-2017, live-unit-tests

I have installed VS2017 Enterprise. It was working fine with few of our existing solutions. Then I tried to enable Live Unit Test for one of the solutions and it crashed with Unknown Error. After that every attempt to launch Visual Studio (note: not the solution) failed with Unknow Error. We are using xunit 2.2.0 for our unit testing. Following is what I found in the Event Viewer

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
Message: StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: Request locate failed with message: Cannot find service module info file '*/emitService.servicehub.service.json' in 'E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\ServiceHub\Services', using discovery services failed: VsixServiceDiscovery: ExternalSettingsManager::GetScopePaths failed to initialize PkgDefManager for E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.ExternalSettingsManager.GetScopePaths(String applicationPath, String suffixOrName, String vsVersion, Boolean isLogged, Boolean isForIsolatedApplication)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.ExternalSettingsManager.CreateForApplication(String applicationPath, IInteropLogger logger)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.VsixServiceDiscovery.DiscoveryService.EnumerateContentLocations()
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.VsixServiceDiscovery.DiscoveryService.EnsureServiceModulesEnumerated()
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.VsixServiceDiscovery.DiscoveryService.discoverService(String serviceName)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__56`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.ThreadingTools.<WithCancellationSlow>d__9`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.<LocateServiceAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.<RequestServiceChannelNameAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.<RequestServiceAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Remote.ServiceHubRemoteHostClient.<RequestServiceAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
Stack:
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FailFast.OnFatalException(System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ErrorReporting.FatalError.Report(System.Exception, System.Action`1<System.Exception>)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ErrorReporting.FatalError.ReportUnlessCanceled(System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Remote.ServiceHubRemoteHostClient+<RequestServiceAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task+DelayPromise.Complete()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task+<>c.<Delay>b__274_1(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback()
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I closed all the instances of VS2017 and it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Closed all the instances and re-opened and it worked fine then.